# Dificuldade com Depuração de código MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Um dos problemas que tenho tido nos estudos é a forma como é feito a depuração do código no mvc, não encontro uma lógica para resolver isso.

OBS:

- A opção amostra de código não está formatando o código corretamente.
- A opção de envio de imagem está com problemas, só envia apos a segunda tentativa

Tenho seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta o conteúdo do arquivo `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: Amigo Tiago, você falou russo agora, mais eu conseguir verificar o problema, eu tenho na Views - Pessoa e não home.

Comment: Tiago, o site esta com problema nestas opções, pelo menos eu não consigo adicionar o código:

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez , agradeço a dica, é isso, controller = "Home", então é só mudar e pronto, funciona normal, da forma que estava eu tinha que adicionar o caminho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique seu no arquivo `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` da sua aplicação há a seguinte regra:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```